# Array split with the help of object categories values of array- Javascript - High Chart

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, highcharts, split

I have result of an array which contain number of objects and need to split with the help of categories. when categories array value of sum reach in 15 then this array will be more split like below result.

Helps are definitely appreciated

> Array

```
 [Object { name="A",  categories=[2]}, Object { name="B",  categories=[3]}, Object { name="C",  categories=[1]}, Object { name="D",  categories=[1]}, Object { name="E",  categories=[1]}, Object { name="F",  categories=[3]}, Object { name="G",  categories=[1]}, Object { name="H",  categories=[1]}, Object { name="I",  categories=[1]}, Object { name="J",  categories=[3]}, Object { name="K",  categories=[2]}, Object { name="L",  categories=[2]}, Object { name="M",  categories=[2]}]
```

More Detail

```
[{"name":"A","categories":["543","301"]},{"name":"B","categories":["100","120","390"]},{"name":"C","categories":["453"]},{"name":"D","categories":["112"]},{"name":"E","categories":["542"]},{"name":"F","categories":["534","545","547"]},{"name":"G","categories":[" 535"]},{"name":"H","categories":["390"]},{"name":"I","categories":["528"]},{"name":"J","categories":["101","492"," 320"]},{"name":"K","categories":["201","210"]},{"name":"L","categories":["102","573"]},{"name":"M","categories":["211","220"]}]
```

> Desired Result

```
[[{"name":"A","categories":["543","301"]},{"name":"B","categories":["100","120","390"]},{"name":"C","categories":["453"]},{"name":"D","categories":["112"]},{"name":"E","categories":["542"]},{"name":"F","categories":["534","545","547"]},{"name":"G","categories":[" 535"]},{"name":"H","categories":["390"]},{"name":"I","categories":["528"]},{"name":"J","categories":["101"]}],[{"name":"J","categories":["492"," 320"]},{"name":"K","categories":["201","210"]},{"name":"L","categories":["102","573"]},{"name":"M","categories":["211","220"]}]]
```

This result part will provide you more help regarding desired result

```
{"name":"J","categories":["101"]}],[{"name":"J","categories":["492"," 320"]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proposal with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and a temporary object.

```js
var array = [{ "name": "A", "categories": ["543", "301"] }, { "name": "B", "categories": ["100", "120", "390"] }, { "name": "C", "categories": ["453"] }, { "name": "D", "categories": ["112"] }, { "name": "E", "categories": ["542"] }, { "name": "F", "categories": ["534", "545", "547"] }, { "name": "G", "categories": [" 535"] }, { "name": "H", "categories": ["390"] }, { "name": "I", "categories": ["528"] }, { "name": "J", "categories": ["101", "492", "320"] }, { "name": "K", "categories": ["201", "210"] }, { "name": "L", "categories": ["102", "573"] }, { "name": "M", "categories": ["211", "220"] }],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        a.categories.forEach(function (b, i) {
            var o = { name: a.name, categories: [] };
            r.count++;
            if (!r.refA || r.count > 15) {
                r.count = 1;
                r.refA = [];
                r.array.push(r.refA);
                i = 0;
            }
            if (!i) {
                r.refA.push(o);
                r.refB = o.categories;
            }
            r.refB.push(b);
        });
        return r;
    }, { array: [], count: 0, refA: undefined, refB: undefined }).array;

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Appreciated your answered but i need that function which return result like this.

`{"name":"J","categories":["101"]}],[{"name":"J","categories":["492"," 320"]}`

Comment: its working now and fulfilled my requirement. Thankyou! you save my day